# How to make PHP countdown with am/pm stored in value?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to show poll countdown in a WordPress widget based on poll end date-time. I am able to pass PHP variable to JavaScript file, but it not actually works as static countdown works

#### 1) My HTML code:

```
<P id="demo">
```

#### 2) My JavaScript file for countdown which called at every second:

```
var countDownDate = new Date("February 21, 2018 16:19").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    // var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
```

This works fine, but i want to make it also work with my dynamic value, my PHP variable which hold the poll end date-time is `$poll_end_date` and it gives value like "February 9, 2018  3:47 pm".

How can I make countdown of day,hour,mint based on this variable `$poll-end-date` value.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you're asking, but have you tried simply passing `February 9, 2018 3:47 pm` as an argument instead of `February 21, 2018 16:19`?

Comment: yes, it display as "NaNd NaNh NaNm ", i just simply want to convert "February 9, 2018 3:47 pm" to "February 9, 2018 3:47", so i can make countdown of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class to convert the date to the required format:

```
<?php
// The date for 'poll_end_date'
$date = 'February 9, 2018 3:47 pm';

// Parse the string based on the expected format
$dtime = DateTime::createFromFormat("F j, Y g:i a", $date);

// Output the date to match the required format
$timestamp = $dtime->format('F j, Y H:i');
?>
```

You can then use this PHP variable inside your usual `<script></script>` tags.

```
<script>
    var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $timestamp; ?>").getTime();
    // ... your script continues below
</script>
```

The methods are well documented here:

- [`DateTime::createfromformat()`](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)
- [`DateTime::format()`](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

You can read up on how the date formats such as `F j, Y H:i` works on [this page](https://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).